# Better way to write while (for) in golang

Tags: for-loop, go, while-loop

I am working on a while loop which a for in Go as in below code

```
ele = path.Dir(str)
for ele != "." {
    functionA()
    ele = path.Dir(ele)
    if ele == "." {
        functionA()
        functionB()
    }
}
```

In the above code as you can see I am calling functionA twice based on a condition inside the while (for)

**Is there a better and cleaner way to do this?**

Comment: You can always `break`...

Comment: Your oversimplified code makes very little sense: `if ele == "."` this condition would never be `true`.

Comment: @zerkms my bad, added more code to make some sense

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly different way to perform the same task.

UPDATE: Updated answer to reflect the new requirements.

```
ele := path.Dir(str)
if ele == "." {
    return
}
for ele != "." {
    functionA()
    ele = path.Dir(ele)
}
functionA()
functionB()
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/KbIH7s45aFR